# Whats the syntax for returning a block from a function where the block has a return value

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have a function which is returning a block, and this code works:

```
typedef void (^AuthenticationBlock)(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge* challenge);

+ (AuthenticationBlock) defaultAuthenticationBlock
{
    return  ^(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *challenge)
    {
    ....
```

But I want to change it so that the block returns a bool:

```
 typedef BOOL (^AuthenticationBlock)(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge* challenge);
```

But I can't figure out what I need to do to get the return statement to compile with this change

Comment: What's the issue? Compiles fine for me if I return a BOOL within the returned block.

Comment: I forgot the return type was automatically inferred by the compiler, so I was trying to change the signature of this part "return  ^(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *challenge)" -  and that's what I couldn't do. Out of curiosity, is it possible to add the return type there?

Comment: Sure `return ^BOOL (NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *challenge) {`